# Need to ignore HostKeyMismatch when logging in using Net::SSH.start()

Tags: net-ssh

`:paranoid => false` in the  Net::SSH.start() does not seem to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a Null verifier instead of false: `:paranoid => Net::SSH::Verifiers::Null.new`.

This is essentially what you should get when passing false but it doesn't appear to always work for some reason.

Please note, just to be explicit. This does not *ignore* the HostKeyMismatch exception, rather it does not even attempt to verify the host key (the exception does not get raised at all).

Answer (score 0):

Just to want to add one more thing to this.

You can also use `remember_host` method of `Net::SSH::HostKeyError` to record this host and key in the known hosts file.

Example :

`begin
.
.
rescue Net::SSH::HostKeyError => e
  e.remember_host!
  retry
end`

Source : http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net/SSH/HostKeyError#remember_host!-instance_method